# Akka-http and handling an empty body during POST

Tags: scala, akka-http

Suppose I am handling a post message.

The Content-Type may be application/xml or application/json. I can unmarshal XML and JSON documents just fine.

However, I would like to handle the case where the POST method is called with an empty body (the content-type may still be xml or json, but the document itself is an empty string). This is for various logging and analytics purposes. Right now, the method fails since the empty body cannot be processed by either one of my unmarshallers.

How do I write an unmarshaller for this case? Or can a unmarshaller handle a null body?

Somewhere in my code I have the following. Do I need more marshallers?

```
  implicit def myUnmarshaller(implicit mat: Materializer): FromEntityUnmarshaller[MyClass] =
    Unmarshaller.firstOf[HttpEntity, MyClass](
      /* myNullBodyMarshaller, */ // do I need this?
      myJsonUnmarshaller, 
      myXmlUnmarshaller
    )
```

or can I modify an existing one? For example, this one?

```
def myJsonUnmarshaller(implicit mat: Materializer): FromEntityUnmarshaller[MyClass] =
    Unmarshaller.byteStringUnmarshaller.forContentTypes(MediaTypes.`application/json`).mapWithCharset { (data, charset) ⇒
      val input: String = if (charset == HttpCharsets.`UTF-8`) data.utf8String else data.decodeString(charset.nioCharset.name)
      val tmp = input.parseJson.convertTo[MyClass]
      MyClass(tmp.A, tmp.B)
    }
```

Comment: This belongs to Some vs None paradigm. You can try changing your `def myJsonUnmarshaller(implicit mat: Materializer): FromEntityUnmarshaller[Option[MyClass]]` and the implementation too so that it either returns `None` or `Some[MyClass] ` .

Comment: I actually did try that, hence the question. The problem is that since I'm expecting a Seq of these MyClass objects, if I do an Option, it still wants an empty Seq (I need to pass "[]" as the JSON, for example). Do I need a custom marshaller for the Seq also? I need a None for the List, not for the individual MyClass inside the List.